How to setup Oauth 2.0 in postman in Springboot authorization server?
I have a auth server running on port 9000, a client gateway running on 8000 and a service running on 8081.
The auth server works correctly from browser as when I try to access my service through gateway, it takes me to the default login page and after authentication, I can hit the service end point. But the same thing is giving me 403 forbidden in postman. I am using oauth2.0 in authorization in postman too with configuration given below. What might be wrong in my configuration? I can generate auth token too but when I send the request, it gives 403 forbidden.
I also tried to use the token generated in bearer authentication but it still gives 403 forbidden
HAR file and auth server log are given below:
auth server log
Browser network
Postman Oauth settings
Security filter code snippet.
Security Filter
Log trace of authorization server
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MB1U9qh16foR8Wuolt8Fsx3n9N4KFiXXhRPPtIEtKko/edit?usp=sharing
EDIT: Now, I am getting /oauth2/authorize not found in postman while sending request.
Postman /oauth2/authorize not found

What are the runtime logs you see in the authz server? Also can you attach a har file for your browser calls?

I have updated the post with the logs for postman call and network of browser.

Can you add the complete stack trace for the request please? From the little you've added, its difficult to see what is happening. Also add a code snippet of your security filter chain

I have added the complete stack trace and security filter snipped but now I am getting oauth2/authorize not found in postman. I have also included the snippet for it.
